# Xcode 4 method braces "{" convention

Tags: xcode, methods, coding-style, conventions, brackets

I switched over to Xcode 4 while it was in beta, and I have mostly been editing existing code so haven't really considered this much until now...

Apple's file templates seem to have switched convention for coding methods. As an example, a pre-Xcode 4 `dealloc` method looked like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
```

In Xcode 4, they now use this style:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

As an avid perfectionist and irritable person, this has me quite miffed! I was brought up on the previous style in Xcode itself, and I'm now finding myself going through every template each time I create one to put the brackets back in the right place!

Please tell me this is a default option that I can change... or will I have to change my own coding style to match (or worse still, "learn to live with it" [*shudder*]!).

Comment: Do a code completion on a while loop, and you will see that there is no line break before the opening brace. So it mixes, which actually is K&R style: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style

Comment: @Gustav: Ah, true enough. I have been happily using plenty of branch statements and loops with the usual braces - I've just incorrectly used the style names in my question. I'll edit my post accordingly. The methods still bug me though! If nothing else, I use code folding extensively and this style makes it much less effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no default option you can change; however:

If you are creating files, you can edit the files in `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates` to your desired coding style.

As for the snippets in the editor, that are inserted when you type `dealloc` alone, and the like; these appear to come from `/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugins/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.plugin`

I wouldn't necessarily recommend editing the files in there; but it's an option.

**Edit:** In order to prevent Xcode updates from breaking your perfectionized templates, you could probably `chmod -w` them, which *should* prevent updates from touching them; but it might cause updates to fail altogether.

Comment: That's handy to know, thanks. I'm not too worried about code snippets - when I type out a lengthy method name such as `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shoulderRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`, I let it complete the name of the method but I always do the brackets myself. It's pretty much just the templates that bug me, so I may well follow your advice and change them manually and hope that future Xcode updates don't ruin my changes.

Comment: Thanks for that, although I might just back the edited templates up in a folder out the way somewhere. I'd worry about getting myself into a situation I can't recover from - I'm no terminal whizz!

Answer (score 3):

I've never been able to get to grips with Xcode indentation. Instead I've ended up with a separate script that calls [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) (for ObjC) or [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) (for plain C) to clean up the code before each commit. That way my coding style (the only sensible one, naturally) is consistently (fanatically?) enforced at all times.

This also catches other typical Xcode annoyances like trailing whitespace, which a reasonable code editor would strip at save time.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'll look into it. Do you need to actively run a script, or can it do it automatically for you as you type? Personally, I'd be a little worried about batch altering hundreds of files simultaneously without seeing the changes as they happen. Have you ever had any trouble with it?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's script only. You create a quite extensive configuration file specifying every aspect of how you prefer the formatting, then run it. I've never had any problems with it. Probably it's best to run it once over all files to straighten things out and commit that as a separate "reformat only" commit, then run it before every commit to keep things in line. Depending on your VCS you might be able to run it as part of the commit operation.

Comment: You can also define it as a macro in Xcode, so you can reformat a file (or perhaps a selection) with a hotkey. Don't have the exact details for that at hand, but I'm sure Google does. :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I may look into this as a solution at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I set up this [github repo](https://github.com/xixixao/xcode-file-templates), to share the fixed template files, which fix your issue.